Authentication mechanism for posting media to Twitter
How do I achieve the correct type and level of authentication to twitter, so that my bot can post images?
The brief background is that X (TAFKA-Twitter) has been stuck in a transition from v1.1 to v2 of their API, so that now you MUST use v1.1 to upload media, and you MUST use v2.0 to tweet.
I've managed to log in using their "twurl" CLI, using OAuth meaning someone has to be present to click a link and generate a sign in code to give back to the CLI program.
But I can't manage to find my way into authenticating my bot so that it will run without a user present.  What am I missing?  Isn't that style of authentication intended for user apps, not daemon-style bots?
I expected for such a usual feature, to find a code sample on their docs site.  I mean:

Sign in
Upload image
Post a tweet referencing the uploaded image

What could be more vanilla?
I've been using the node-twitter-api-v2 npm package.  I've ensured that the account is configured as a "managed" account and have issued read-write keys.
Yet, every combination of keys I submit is returned with 403.

The answer is best described in the docs for node-twitter-api-v2
where it is explained that the three-part authentication process is definitely needed.  However, the OAuth 1.0 authentication process to Twitter does not have a built-in expiration time for the keys obtained.  In brief, the process is like this:

Post a call to generate an authentication link, using the CONSUMER keys obtained from developer.twitter.com.
Use the link to generate a PIN number.
Use the PIN number to log in again and obtain oauth key and secret.
In subsequent logins, use both of the "consumer" keys, as well as the oath key and secret obtained in step 3.

Code that does this can be found here.
